# Binary Search to search a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, binary-search

I have a code which first sorts the emails into alphabetical order and then attempts to use binary search to search a user inputted email from a list. However, I have been stuck on how to do this for so long and haven't found any solutions on the error I get and how to fix it. Here is my code

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)
    logindata = list(logindata)
    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0
        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
                temp = logindata[Count]
                logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
                logindata[Count+1]=temp
                NoSwaps=1
    return tuple(logindata)

def BinarySearch(logindata,ItemSought):
    First=0
    Last=len(logindata)-1
    ItemFound = False
    SearchFailed = False
    while ItemFound == False or SearchFailed == False:
        Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
        if logindata[Midpoint] == ItemSought:
            ItemFound = True
            print("Item Found")
            break

        elif logindata[Midpoint] > ItemSought:
            Last = Midpoint - 1
        else:
            First = Midpoint + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["tom@gmail.com","Password1"],["harry@gmail.com","Password2"],["jake@gmail.com","Password3"]
    logindata=BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
    ItemSought=input("Enter username")
    BinarySearch(logindata,ItemSought)
```

The error I currently get is :

```
elif logindata[Midpoint] > ItemSought:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > str()
```

Comment: You probably want `elif logindata[Midpoint][0] > ItemSought:`

Comment: `logindata[Midpoint][0]`, not 1 I would imagine

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yep. corrected.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This gets rid of the error where would the output go to tell the user the item was found?

Comment: If the item is found, your code prints "Item Found".  It doesn't do anything if the item is not found.  I wold recommend that you change that so it returns `True` or `False`, and then do the printing outside the function

Comment: @PatrickHaugh How come after inputting the correct email with the list it doesnt print out item found when it should?

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a username/password pair (e.g. `["tom@gmail.com","Password1"]`) with a username (e.g. `"tom@gmail.com"`).

You need to extract the username from `logindata[Midpoint]` before comparing it to `ItemSought`.

Comment: I have extracted the username from it but the code doesnt actually work , it doesnt find the username when the user inputs the correct email?